# Not taking into account condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a parameter @UserID, it can be 0 (no userid assigned) or id itself.
The structure of query is as follows

```
if @UserID > 0
select ...
where UserID=@UserID
      ...
else if @UserID = 0
select ...
where ...
```

What I want is the following structure

```
select ...
where if @UserID >0 then UserID = @UserID else disregard this condition
      ...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set null as parameter value instead of 0 (zero)

```
declare @id int

set @id = null

select * 
from   users 
where  (id = @id) 
       or (@id is null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a case statement as:

```
 WHERE 1 = CASE 
           WHEN @UserID >0 and UserID = @UserID  THEN 1
           ELSE 0
           END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE (@userID<>0 AND id = @userID) OR
      (@userID=0 AND 1=1)
```

`1=1` is used for ignoring WHERE condition which would happend if `@userID` is supplied value **0**

Answer (score 1):

I would like to recommend [Erland Sommarskog's article, "**Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL**"](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).

One pattern mentioned there is the following (in your case):

```
SELECT … WHERE @UserID = 0 OR UserID = @UserID
--             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In plain English: If `@UserID = 0`, then the whole `OR` condition evaluates to true (and thus doesn't lead to any records being filtered out) no matter whether `UserID = @UserID` or not. Therefore when `@UserID = 0` the latter criterion essentially gets omitted.

> <sub>**Remark #1**: Usually, `NULL` is chosen instead of 0.</sub>
>
> <sub>**Remark #2:** If I remember correctly, this pattern might affect the query optimizer in a bad way, so if that is the case for you, perhaps read up on it in the article mentioned above. I have only checked very quickly, I think Erland Sommarskog suggests that the query optimizer hint `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` is used.</sub>

Comment: Can you expand your answer please?